# How can I identify a string by its last four digits without trimming to a new column?

Tags: vba, excel

Essentially, the goal of my macro is to get a quantity associated with an item number. The item number is indicated by the variable td, which the user enters in the dialog box.

Item numbers appear in the following format: TD4040672B, TD3794160, etc.

However, I don't want the user to have to enter the full number. The last four digits will suffice. Right now, this is what I have.

```
   For i = 1 To 500
    If Cells(i, 11).Value = td Then

        Cells(i, 4).Activate
        qty = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

End If

Next i
```

Without trimming the item numbers on the page, is there a way to locate a cell by last four digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
Right$(ActiveCell.Value, 4)
```